# Can a security rule in Firebase allow write access for a specific user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

trying to get this to work :

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid == simplelogin:2",
  }
}
```

I want just a specific user to have a write control over everything (for now). How do I make this work?

Comment: You need to put quotes around the user's uid and remove the trailing comma, so `".write": "auth.uid == 'simplelogin:2'"`

Comment: This is pretty fundamental stuff and covered extensively in [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/).